# Native Code Profiling on Android multicore phones

Tags: android, performance, native, multicore

What are the ways of profiling native code on Android multicore phones?

I am seeking profile based on wall-time/real-time elapsed, CPU time, system time used in carrying out instructions in a method.

I used gprof but it seems that it measures only the CPU time for each function.
Oprofile needs kernel build, so that is an over-kill.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to use Intel VTune Amplifier. This profiler allows you to collect hotspots with stacks on **Android** devices without root or any OS modification. 
Here is simple guide:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-vtune-amplifier-on-non-rooted-android-devices